# Greater than and less than in switch statements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why this code does not work

```
let userName = 'roy';
const userQuestion = 'Do you do CrossFit?';
userName ? console.log('Hello ' + userName + ' !') : console.log('Hello!');
console.log(`The user asked: ${userQuestion}`);
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
let eightBall = '';
console.log(randomNumber);

switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
        eightBall = 'It is certain';
        break;
    case 1:
        eightBall = 'It is defidedly so';
        break;
    case randomNumber >= 1:
        eightBall = 'we cant tell';
        break;
}

console.log(` The eight ball answered: ${eightBall}`);
```

Trying to generate "we can tell" when the number is greater than 1 but it's not printing anything. Am I using a switch statement wrong?

Comment: use `default:` instead of `case randomNumber >= 1:`

Comment: *"Am I using a switch statement wrong?"* - yes. Please read how javascript switch case statement works.

Comment: please do not use a ternary for an expession without assingment rr use of the result.

Answer (score 2):

Use a default with an `if` statement inside like so:

```js
let randomNumber = 100
let eightBall = ''

switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
        eightBall = 'It is certain';
        break;
    case 1:
        eightBall = 'It is defidedly so';
        break;
    default:
        if(randomNumber >= 1)
            eightBall = 'we cant tell';
        break;
}

console.log(` The eight ball answered: ${eightBall}`);
```

Comment: Given OP's code `randomNumber` will never be negative and the test `if(randomNumber >= 1)` is redundant, it will always be true

Answer (score 2):

`case` takes an argument to be equal too, not a boolean expression. You could just use the `default` branch:

```
switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
        eightBall = 'It is certain';
        break;
    case 1:
        eightBall = 'It is defidedly so';
        break;
    default: // Here!
        eightBall = 'we cant tell';
        break;
}
```

Comment: It's always good to have an explanation on why the OP's code didn't work, +1 in my books